# How to animate the background of table with a white gradient using CSS3

Tags: html, css, animation, linear-gradients

I need to animate table like in the image below:
[image: Animated GIF of an empty table with striped rows. The rows with a gray background also have a white gradient moving from left to right.]

The structure is

```
<table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody class='table-body'>
        <tr></tr> <!-- It can be any number of rows -->
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to do it in this way

```
.table-body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #E8E8E8, #ffffff, #E8E8E8);
  background-size: 200% 200%;
  animation: Animation 3s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Animation {
  0%{
    background-position-x: 0%
  }
  100%{
    background-position-x: 100%
  }
}
```

Also I tried to add `after` on `.table` set to it `position: absolute;` `width`, `height`, `background-color`, and move it from left to right using animation.
But I can't hardcode height property so I can't use in this way.
Could you advice me a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had good luck with the following. Note the addition of the td's, the change in background-position for the final keyframe, and switching the order of the keyframes.

```
<table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody class='table-body'>
        <tr><td>Text goes here</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Text goes here</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Text goes here</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Text goes here</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<style>
.table-body {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #E8E8E8, #ffffff, #E8E8E8);
  background-size: 200% 200%;
  animation: Animation 3s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Animation {
  0%{
    background-position-x: 200%
  }
  100%{
    background-position-x: 0%
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Great! Glad it could help out! If my answer worked out for you, would you mind accepting my answer as 'correct'? Thank you!